# Selenium get Build info, System info, Session info & Driver info

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I recently had an error in my script, wrong locator, an got:

```
(Session info: chrome=44.0.2403.125)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.16.333243 (0bfa1d3575fc1044244f21ddb82bf870944ef961),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:16:47'
System info: host: 'xyz123', ip: '10.1.2.11', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_75'
```

The error is fixed now, but this information would be very useful for my reporting. Can I get this somehow, without producing errors :-)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all properties by using

`System.getProperties()`

or by using

`System.out.println("All Properties: "+System.getProperties().toString())`

so you can see all properties and their value. If you want a certain property you can just use:

```
System.getProperty("os.name")
```

so here you would get the property value of `os.name` which contains "Windows 7" in your case.

Comment: I missed the fact, that i'm useing Perl.
In the docs for Selenium::Remote::Driver and Selenium::Remote::WebElement i can't find getProperties

Comment: Oh, actually these is not WebElement or Driver .. it is the System class form java.lang package which includes the properties. I don't know how it is in PERL but it should also have an own (not selenium related) class which includes all system properties. Maybe this helps you: http://perldoc.perl.org/Config.html .. could be that also selenium properties are included there as it is in java

Comment: print Dumper $driver->status;

Description:
  Query the server's current status. All server implementations
  should return two basic objects describing the server's current
  platform and when the server was built.

Comment: Browser details can be founde here: my $capab = $driver->get_capabilities();

Answer (score 1):

import org.openqa.selenium.internal.BuildInfo;

```
BuildInfo info = new BuildInfo();
String infoString = info.toString();
System.out.println(infoString);
```